# Baire category theorem to show a set is dense.

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

Consider $A_j$ a sequence of subsets of $[0,1]$ s.t. for each $N\geq 1$, $\bigcup_{j=N}^\infty A_j$ is open and dense in $[0,1]$.

If $S$ is the set of points $x \in [0,1]$ s.t. $x \in A_j$ for infinitely many $j$, then I wish to show that $S$ is dense. I am also unsure if $S$ needs to be an open set.

I have tried to find a way to apply the Baire category theory, but I haven't had any success. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $S=\{x\in[0,1]\,|x\in A_j\,,j=1,2,...\}$ then $S=\{x\,|\,x\in\cap_{j=1}^\infty A_j\}$, since all $A_j$ lay in $[0,1]$, we can see that:

$S=\cap_{j=1}^\infty A_j$, and by baire category theorem, this set is dense.

Also I believe $S$ may not need to be open.

I did not take in the first part where $\cup_{j=N}^\infty A_j$ is open and dense in $[0,1]$ $\forall N\ge 1$, but this implies that each $A_j$ is open and dense in $[0,1]$, so the above holds.

Comment: Does $S$ necessarily satisfy $S=\{x\in [0,1]|x \in A_j,j=1,2,...\}$? Could the indexing start at some other number and there would still be infinitely many $A_j$? I think this is where I became confused.

Comment: This is a good point, it could be:

$S=\{x\in[0,1]|x\in A_j,j\in \alpha\}$, where $\alpha$ is a countable index set, then $S=\cap_{j\in\alpha}A_j$, which by baire category is dense, since each $A_j$ is dense

Comment: Thank you very much, I can see that we can still apply Baire's theorem as the index set is countable. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, happy to help. :)

Comment: @user147416 There is a mistake in here. It's not the set $\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j$ that is dense, but $\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{j=N}^{\infty}A_j$. You cannot conclude that $A_j$ is open and dense from the fact that $\bigcup_{j=N}^{\infty}A_j$ is.

Comment: But it does imply that there are inifinitely many $A_j$ that are dense, by looking at the "tail" of this union, so we apply the theory to those sets.

Comment: Late counterexample: Let $\{q_1,q_2,q_3,\ldots\}$ be a denumeration of the rationals and put $A_j:=\left(q_j-\frac{1}{j},q_j+\frac{1}{j}\right)$. Then $\bigcup_{j=N}^{\infty}A_j$ is open and dense, since it contains all but finitely many rationals, but $A_j$ is not dense for all $j\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: No, it is not open and dense for all $N$.

Comment: For all $N\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{q_1,\ldots,q_N\}\subset \bigcup_{j=N}^{\infty}A_j$ and $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{q_1,\ldots,q_N\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But this must all take place in $[0,1]$ which is a bounded set. So the nature of this situation is different.

Comment: The counterexample still applies. Take a denumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$ and put $A_j:=\left(q_j-\frac{1}{100j},q_j+\frac{1}{100j}\right)\cap [0,1]$. In this way, we can even find $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$.

Comment: The whole union is dense, but if we romove a finite amount of balls of finite radius we lose density.